# Which statements are equivalences and which are implications?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I solved a task and wanted to ask whether I did the task correctly.

> Put $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftarrow$, $\iff$ in the box so that the logical statement is true.

What I did:

$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{N}:x>5 \iff  \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{5}  $$
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}:x>2 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{2}  $$
$$ \forall p\in\mathbb{R}:|p|=1 \Rightarrow  p \ge -1 $$
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{Q}: x \ge 0 \Rightarrow  x^4 \ge 0 $$

I just put a $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftarrow$ and $\iff$ between these inequalities, so only they have to be checked.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very well done!

Comment: Thank you for checking :).